# what ways of TS searches are available in Gaussian09

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software

I have a system for which I could not find the transition state using Gaussian09 corresponding to the experimental product formation. I have tried

```
opt=modredundant
```

route command fixing the two atoms in the (C-C) bond formation. It worked well showing the vibration in the bond formation in this direction (one -ve frequency of about -200), however, when i release the constraint and do a TS search, it gave a TS for a remote bond rotation (no longer along C-C bond formation).

I have tried to do a PES scan along the C-C bond forming direction varying the bond length from 3 Angstrom to 1.2 Angstrom, there is no maxima (but a minimum) within this range; the energy of the system only increases when the C-C bond approaches too close to each other.

What other ways can I try?

Comment: I'm interested in this, can you explain how you want to find a TS using frozen coordinates? Every time you set a coordinate to a non-minimum configuration you will get at least one negative frequence, this doesn't say anything about if that's a TS.  And did you do berny afterwards?

Comment: yes, you are right, i think. when you freeze the atoms for which you expect the bond formation and do an opt=modredundant, you are checking if you could get a TS after you release the constraint. indeed a berny optimisation for TS search is done after you have confirmed the existence of a negative vibrational frequency in the direction of the desired bond formation.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try the *Synchronous Transit-Guided Quasi-Newton* (STQN) method requested by `Opt=QST2` or `Opt=QST3` in the route section. It is described in many different places, including the [Gaussian official web-site](http://www.gaussian.com/g_whitepap/qst2.htm).

Note that

> **QST2** requires two molecule specifications, for the reactant and
>   product, as its input, while **QST3** requires three molecule
>   specifications: the reactant, the product, and an initial structure
>   for the transition state, in that order.

Another important thing to whatch for is that

> The order of the atoms must be identical within all molecule
>   specifications.

Comment: thanks Wildcat! yes indeed! this is one method that I forgot! will try and update if it works for my system!

Comment: it did not work for my system; it gave a C-C rotation outside the C-C bond-forming carbon atoms. This is the same as the remote bond rotation that I obtained when I release my constraint in TS search starting from the modredundant results..

Comment: @XZhang, without details it would be difficult to suggest something.